# Notifications from Workbench included content type

Tags: 7, notifications, workbench

I added a new content type for my drupal 7 site and I have a form in this content type. It has the workbench enabled in this form so that the moderator can approve the submissions and close the forms if they are complete.

The functionality that I am looking to implement now is mailing the user upon the status change of the form. i.e, if the form changes from draft to closed, the user should be notified. I looked for modules or related content for implementing this, but could not find any. What is the best way to do this? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the Rules module: http://drupal.org/project/rules

It should be pretty straightforward, once you figure out how to use Rules. (You can find some video tutorials here: http://drupalize.me/videos/basics-rules-link)

Basically, you are going to create a rule that is triggered when a node's workbench moderation state changes. When the rule runs, it will send an email. In that email, you should be able to include tokens (http://drupal.org/project/token) that will be specific to the node that was just changed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, meanwhile I wrote a custom module using the hook_node_presave and drupal_mail function. It works perfect.